# Detecting if user has made changes to FontDialog object

Tags: vb.net, dialog

I've got a `FontDialog` box called `aFontDialog`.

Can I detect changes made to this dialog box?

Initially my object creates the dialog using this code `aFontDialog.ShowDialog`, the user than makes changes, then if the user is happy with their changes then the application will receive `Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`:

[image]

Is it possible to detect any changes made to this dialog by the user? Will I need to record the state of the different aspects of the dialog before and then compare to how they are after - or are there some properties or methods built into this dialog box that help me find any changes?

Comment: as far as i know you need to compare before state with the after state means properties of the FontDialog object e.g. (Color, Font...) see the properties @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important concern here is - *why do you need to know the changes*. See, font is usually not a transactional object, so you normally don't need to avoid excessive network traffic or minimize number of database roundtrips.

I would just look if user pressed OK. If yes, set the new font, regardless of how similar it is to your current one. It's just one line of code - simple as assigning this new font to the old one:

```
Me.Font = MyFontDialog.Font 'Me could be any control in this case
```

Besides, I think it is your only way, if the font is different. Meaning you cannot for example set `Font.Bold = True`, because it's read-only. And it would not take a lot of processing time either, so no point in optimizing it.

If you really want to, you can examine `FontDialog.Font` after checking `DialogResult` for OK, and compare to what you passed there, although I don't see where this would be useful.